# Какую роль играет "за" в предложении "Что это был за чудный человек"?

Tags: синтаксис, морфология, синтаксический-разбор, частица

*За* -- довольно распространённый предлог, который употребляется с винительным или творительным падежом. В предложении:

> «Если бы вы знали, что это **был за чудный человек**, пани»

падеж явно именительный! Что нарушает вообще какую бы то ни было сколько-нибудь разумную синтаксическую трактовку данного предложения.

И теперь вопрос: что за конструкция здесь используется и в качестве какой части речи здесь употребляется слово *за*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Что за* (в данном случае *за* не предлог, а часть сложной частицы) — это разговорная восклицательная частица, употребляющаяся в трех случаях:

1) при усилении вопроса;
2) при усилении качества или свойства;
**3) при выражении эмоциональной оценки (восхищения, возмущения, осуждения и т. п.)**.

В вашем примере третий случай: рассказчик восхищается неким человеком (а вполне возможно, что испытывает резко противоположные чувства).

Иногда эта частица может «разрываться» словами *был*, *это* и т. п., что, собственно, и можно наблюдать в приведенном предложении.

Comment: Как стать модератором ? @Aer

Comment: @Cloud стоит дождаться, когда будут объявлены выборы. Для этого следите за Метой: https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/. Подробнее о модераторах: https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators.

Answer (score 5):

Сочетание "что за" (здесь присутствует в разнесённом варианте "что... за") в данном случае используется в качестве *эмоционально-экспрессивной частицы с усилительным значением* (к таковым относятся: ну, ну и, что за, как, какой, какая, какие),

> см. Жеребило Т. В. Словарь лингвистических терминов, изд. 5-е, стр.
>   453:
>
> https://www.myfilology.ru/media/user_uploads/Tutorials/Zherebilo_T_V_slovar_lingvisticheskih_terminov.pdf

Answer (score 0):

А я рассматривала бы это предложение по-другому. Здесь ЭТО - подлежащее в именительном падеже, его можно заменить местоимением ОН.
ЧЕЛОВЕК - дополнение в винительном падеже с предлогом ЗА.

Comment: Так не получается, т.к. словосочетание *чудный человек* не может быть в винительном падеже, а это согласованное сочетание слов.